# Modifying gstreamer debug level values

Tags: debugging, logging, enumeration, gstreamer

I want to modify the values in the gstreamer GstDebuglevel enumeration (You can find it in gst/gstinfo.h). Will it work if I simply change the enum values in the gstinfo.h or should I have to do any other modification? I want to give lower priority to debug related log dumps. How can I achieve the following.

I want something like this:

```
typedef enum { 
GST_LEVEL_NONE = 0, 
GST_LEVEL_ERROR = 1, 
GST_LEVEL_WARNING = 2, 
GST_LEVEL_FIXME = 3, 
GST_LEVEL_INFO = 4, 
GST_LEVEL_LOG = 6, 
GST_LEVEL_TRACE = 7, 
/* add more */ 
GST_LEVEL_MEMDUMP = 9, 
/* add more */ 
GST_LEVEL_DEBUG = 10, 
GST_LEVEL_COUNT 
}GstDebugLevel;
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the enum value and rebuilding gstreamer is enough.

I tested it with this enum:

```
typedef enum {
  GST_LEVEL_NONE = 0,
  GST_LEVEL_ERROR,
  GST_LEVEL_WARNING,
  GST_LEVEL_INFO,
  GST_LEVEL_DEBUG=10,
  GST_LEVEL_LOG=5,
  GST_LEVEL_FIXME = 6,
  GST_LEVEL_TRACE = 7,
  /* add more */
  GST_LEVEL_MEMDUMP = 9,
  /* add more */
  GST_LEVEL_COUNT
} GstDebugLevel;
```

And it did not output DEBUG level traces on the same GST_DEBUG value.

Comment: Hi Martin, Thank you for your reply. After modifying enum do I have compile gstreamer and all the components or will it work if I compile only gstreamer? And I have one more doubt in the enumeration given by you, the value of GST_LEVEL_COUNT is 10 here and won't it conflict with GST_LEVEL_DEBUG value?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Just gstreamer is enough. 
You are correct: in my example GST_LEVEL_COUNT and GST_LEVEL_DEBUG have the same value, meaning GST_LEVEL_COUNT would probably not display correctly. But you get the point.